# Set RTL for Google sheet in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread, gspread-formatting

Is there a way to set RTL (Right-to-left) and LTR (left-to-right) to sheets/cells in Python, perhaps with [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/) or [gspread-formatting](https://readthedocs.org/projects/gspread-formatting/) packages? Does Google Sheet's API even support this?

I couldn't find any related documentation...

**UPDATE:** I eventually *did* find right-to-left reference in Google Sheet's API for [sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#sheetproperties) and for [text in cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#TextFormatRun). So this may be a matter of implementation in the python packages. I went ahead and opened a [gspread package feature request](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/1116) and [gspread-formatting package feature request](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting/issues/43)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to change "RTL" and "LTR" of the sheet in Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
client =  # Please use your client of gspread.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set your sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
data = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateSheetProperties": {
                "properties": {"rightToLeft": True, "sheetId": sheet.id},
                "fields": "rightToLeft",
            }
        }
    ]
}
spreadsheet.batch_update(data)
```

- When this script is run, the sheet of `sheetName` of Spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId` is used.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/spreadsheet.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

  > `rightToLeft`: True if the sheet is an RTL sheet instead of an LTR sheet.